# Accessing arrays inside ctypes union

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using the python ctypes for the first time . My intention is to convert a python list into an array which is located inside the ctype union. However, when I try to do this I get TypeError. I have pasted my code below since I have not been able to find any suitable examples for this scenario: 
Please comment.

```
from ctypes import * 
class state_struct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("loc0", c_uint32 * 3),
                ("loc1", c_uint32 ),
                ("loc2", c_uint32 * 12),
                ("loc3", c_uint32 * 28),
                ("loc4", c_uint32 * 2),
               ]

class state_union(Union):
    _fields_ = [("state_struct", state_struct),
                ("data", c_uint32 * 46),

                ]
def populate_union(): 
    u = state_union()
    l = [1,2,3] 
    for i in iter(l):
        u.state_struct.loc0 = i 


populate_union()
```

TypeError: expected c_uint_Array_3 instance, got int

Answer (score 1):

`state_struct.loc0` is an array of length 3. You need to index into its elements if you want to assign integers to them.

For example:

```
l = [1,2,3]
for index, value in enumerate(l):
    u.state_struct.loc0[index] = value
```

or you could assign the whole list in one go using slice indexing:

```
u.state_struct.loc0[:] = l
```